# Different deployment targets on app extension

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

Recently added a stickers extension to one of our iOS apps. Since it's packaged together, I am curious if the deployment targets need to match ?

For instance. Our iOS App has a deployment target of 8.0, and the stickers extension has an deployment target of 10.0.

Will this impact users who have an iOS version of lower than 10? or will they just not receive the app extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment Targets do not need to match.